# UIStoryboard and inheritance

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have an AnimalViewController. It it a base view controller. I also have the AnimalViewController Scene in UIStoryBoard.

I have a question about inheritance.

```
@interface BearViewController : AnimalViewController
@interface LionViewController : AnimalViewController
```

Is it possible to instantiate BearViewController with AnimalViewController Scene?

PS BearViewController and LionViewController have the same interface as  AnimalViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use xib instead storyboard.

```
BearViewController *bearVC = [[BearViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Animal" bundle:nil];
LionViewController *lionVC = [[LionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Animal" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: [The strategy pattern is an another way for this problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17381927/419348)

Answer (score -1):

You can you do the following but I don't think storyboards were designed to do something like this, you will still be having `AnimalViewController` object just casted to `subclass` so basically you will gain nothing (except different pointer type) and get runtime crashes when you call any of `BearViewController` defined methods later:

```
BearViewController *bearViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnimalViewController"];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:bearViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: The cast doesn't change the actual runtime object.  It simply tells the compiler to "trust you"... that the object returned at runtime will be a BearViewController.  If the scene is configured to be an AnimalViewController, that's what will be returned at runtime...  So the code you've written doesn't instantiate a BearViewController.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant... it gives you nothing except different pointer type.

Comment: The question was about how to instantiate BearViewController. This answer does not address that.