# Dynamic Subclass for a control in a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, interface-builder

I have an app which users use to record their body measurements. Currently it uses a UIPickerView, but I want to write a custom control which looks more like a (flat, non skeu!) tape measure.

Users can use either metric or imperial measurements and I want to have a different class for each representation as the current code for the UIPicker with them in together is very messy.

I also want to be using interface builder if possible.

So I want to build something like this:

[image: UML]

and then in IB I select the top level class. In the viewDidLoad I want to select the type of subclass to load.

[image: Interface Builder]

My question really is, am I taking the wrong direction here? As I've started implementing this I've realised that controls are initialised using awakeFromNib before viewDidLoad gets hit.

What's the best way to achieve what I'm after? Or am I over simplifying? What's the simplest approach that will go in the direction I want to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good way to achieve this behavior is using the Strategy Pattern as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379980/how-to-change-a-uiviewcontroller-class-name-in-a-uistoryboard-at-runtime)

You can have just one subclass: `HorizontalSlider` with a `strategy` property and multiple helper classes to do the real stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Raúl that looks like a good approach. Is there a way to pass a runtime value from the view controller into HorizontalSlider before the awakeFromNib is called? Otherwise I'll have to add some extra dependencies into HorizontalSlider.

Comment: Actually passing messages between objects before `awakeFromNib` is discouraged, since the order in which objects are instantiated is not guaranteed. You can read more about it in `awakeFromNib` reference. Maybe you could implement a custom `initWithCoder:` or `init` method in `HorizontalSilder` to do what you want? Only one is called  before `awakeFromNib` (If the class conforms to `NSCoding` protocol `initWithCoder:` is called, otherwise the `init` method is used)